# Blueprint CSS : showgrid not working

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I just started out with Blueprint css . I am trying to use showgrid class , but it is not showing me any grid in the screen . Below is the code . Please let me know if I am missing something .

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <title> Book Haven</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueprint/src/grid.css" type="text/css">


    </head>

      <body>
    <div class="container showgrid">
        <div id="header" class="span-24 last">
            <h1 id="book_haven"><img src="bookicon.png" alt="Book header image" id="header-image" /> </h1>
        </div>
        <hr />


     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a lot of sub-directories in your blueprint/ directory, are you sure you are including all files correctly ?

Last thing to check is where the grid.png file is located. As described in grid.css file line 22, the file should be in the directory src/

Comment: yeah. everything seems fine . Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: try to check with firebug if the showgrid div actually loads the specific rule of grid.css file.

Comment: one doubt . When the page loads , will clicking on css tab in firebug show all the css files loaded ?

Comment: yea...to check one specific rule if its loaded or not, right-click on your element and choose "Inspect element" (in english), on the bottom-right if you see the showgrid line of grid.css, so it's currently loaded. Otherwise not.

Comment: Actually , it has loaded it . I clicked on the css tab . grid.css is appearing there .

Answer (score 1):

Download http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/zipball/master and copy the blueprint folder.

css class showgrid makes use of blueprint/src/grid.png file